# How to use colored strings in a listview?

Tags: android, string, android-arrayadapter

In my strings.xml file i have a string like this: `<string name="example">some text <font color="#FF00FF">%1$s</font> some text</string>`

I have an `ArrayAdapter<String>` which uses the following kind of listitem:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_default_textview"
    android:textColor="@color/secondary">
</TextView>
```

I use `arrayAdapter.add(getString(R.string.example, parameter))` but it does not use the colors that i defined in the string. it uses `@color/secondary`for the entire string instead. In a 'normal' textview the custom colors inside the string work, so I guess the problem is about the ArrayAdapter, but I have no idea what the problem is. Or in other words: Is there a way to make the custom colors in the string work with the array adapter?

Answer (score 2):

> I have an `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Change that to `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`. `Strings` do not have formatting. `CharSequences` do.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution!
But I needed to do the following as well to make it work:
`<string name="example"><![CDATA[**string goes here**]]></string>`
And this: `arrayAdapter.add(Html.FromHtml(getString(...)));`
(I tried this before, but it didn't work since my `ArrayAdapter<String>` wasn't an `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`)
You maybe should add this to your answer. :)